perl: Use "-" for standard input with 3-arg open
The old 2-arg version of open (i.e., open FILEHANDLE,EXPR) to open a file in perl is deprecated. For security reasons, it should be replaced by the 3-arg version open FILEHANDLE,MODE,EXPR. There is one case, though, where the 3-arg version behaves differently from the 2-arg version:
2-arg open interprets the special filename - as standard input. For instance, both
echo foo | perl -e 'open my $fh, "-"; $_ = <$fh>; print $_;'

and
echo foo | perl -e 'open my $fh, "<-"; $_ = <$fh>; print $_;'

produce the output foo. In the 3-arg version, the special interpretation of - has disappeared, however:
echo foo | perl -e 'open my $fh, "<", "-"; $_ = <$fh>; print $_;'

prints nothing.
What's the standard or recommended way to emulate this feature of 2-arg open using 3-arg open? (In the concrete application, the filename is an argument of the program which may or may not be -.)

I guess the obvious answer is to if ($filename eq "-") { $fh = STDIN } else { open $fh ... } or so. But that's not too one-liner-y.

"In the concrete application, the filename is an argument of the program which may or may not be -". And if it's - you would like it to be interpreted as meaning stdin or stdout depending on context rather than the file called -? Can't users use /dev/stdin//dev/stdout for that?

@StéphaneChazelas I want my program to behave in the same way as cat, sed, or numerous other Unix utilities: - in the middle of a list of input files means standard input. If users really, really want to read the file -, they can use ./- instead.

BTW, -h and --help are also valid filenames; still we expect users to write ./-h and ./--help if they really want to call their files in this way.

For the 3-arg form equivalent of those 2-arg shortcuts, see the section about duplicating file handles in perldoc -f open:

Duping filehandles
You may also, in the Bourne shell tradition, specify an EXPR
beginning with ">&", in which case the rest of the string is
interpreted as the name of a filehandle (or file descriptor,
if numeric) to be duped (as in dup(2)) and opened. You may
use "&" after ">", ">>", "<", "+>", "+>>", and "+<". The
mode you specify should match the mode of the original
filehandle. (Duping a filehandle does not take into account
any existing contents of IO buffers.) If you use the
three-argument form, then you can pass either a number, the
name of a filehandle, or the normal "reference to a glob".

$ echo test | perl -e '
  open my $fi, "<&", \*STDIN or die;
  open my $fo, ">&", \*STDOUT or die;
  $line = <$fi>; print $fo $line'
test

Note that - is as valid a file name as any, one of the reasons to avoid the 2-args form of open.
If you want your program to handle - as meaning stdin when opened for reading (and uname| to mean the file called uname|, not the output of uname and the other dangerous  special cases supported by the 2-args form of open), you'd want to do it by hand:
# for input:
if ($filename eq '-') {
  $fh = *STDIN;
} else {
  open $fh, '<', $filename or die;
}

# for output
if ($filename eq '-') {
  $fh = *STDOUT;
} else {
  open $fh, '>', $filename or die;
}


What's the practical difference between this solution and $fi = STDIN (as in ilkkachu's comments above)?

@Uwe, $fi = *STDIN would likely be preferable. open $fi, "<&", \*STDIN I think would be closer to what open $fi, "<-" does.
